# Why is Maggie so angry at Glenn in Walking Dead S03E10?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In the episode "*Home*", after Glenn and Maggie return home, Glenn is furious about what may or may not have happened during the previous 2 episodes, and Maggie starts giving Glenn the cold shoulder - refusing to talk to him.

> Maggie yells at Glenn, asking what else she was supposed to have done (referring to removing her clothes for The Governor), but Glenn has made comments to the group that Maggie was a victim in her experiences in Woodbury - not that he blamed her for anything.

Watching the show with our group, we were unable to come up with a concrete, or even most-likely answer as to just why she was so angry.

Answer (score 6):

This came up on the aftershow with the show runner. I think the consensus among the panel was that it was because, while the event had actually happened to Maggie, Glenn was focused on his own anger and reaction to it.

Furthermore, I think that she is ready to move on, but Glenn's reaction is keeping her where she is, as a victim.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of humiliation torture leaves deep scars.  She is suffering from a form of PTSD which is causing her to lash out - she is probably feeling a mix of the following:

- Humiliated
- Guilty
- Furious at the Governer
- Angry at Glen for being important enough for her to try to protect him by undressing
- Guilty at being angry at Glen
- Angry at Glen for not being able to rescue her
- Guilty at being angry at Glen again
- Angry at Rick for not doing something to stop it happening
- Horrified and worried about Glen's torture
- Frustrated that she cannot console Glen after his experiences
- Frustrated she was not able to help him more and stop the torture

This is a horrible cocktail of emotions which will cause her mood swings, depression etc even though she knows a lot of the feelings are irrational.

Comment: I don't agree with the above about PTSD at all. it's Glenn experiencing that, if anyone is. He's making the situation his own thing - he only seems to care about whether or not she was raped or not, it's controlling and possessive. He's objectifying her, like something he owns has been violated, rather than actually being sensitive to her feelings.

Comment: You honestly do not think that someone who went through what Maggie went through would suffer an emotional trauma!??!

Comment: @Rach, Welcome to Sci-Fi stack exchange. Have you taken the [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)? Here on Sci-Fi SE we value posts that answer the question being asked. Unfortunately I've had to convert your answer to a comment. Please keep trying though!

Answer (score 0):

because glenn focused more on what had happened and lingering in the moment, a moment Maggie wanted to forget and she would rather have glenn helping her move on and showing his love for her rather than trying to get her to talk about it to make himself feel better (in a sense, he did not want to intentionally make her feel bad)

Comment: A quote to support this would be good.

Answer (score -3):

She told glenn with upmost truth she was not sexually assaulted physically. Glenn didn't believe her and let his ego take over. He wouldn't be able to deal with Maggie being sexually assaulted for real and that understandably made Maggie furious with him because he was acting like a child and not caring for what really happened.

That's what I think anyways.

Someone explained in the chat perfectly. It's like glenn is in a very possessive state of mind and Maggie is something he owns  that could potentially be ruined  because of the situation  and he's obsessing over it, despite telling him twice, that it didn't happen. I would also be furious at glenn and feel alone.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Are you purely guessing here though, or is there any tangible evidence, such as a quote, that'd  support this interpretation? If you can, please [edit] this answer to better evidence this interpretation.